# how do you call a class variable from another class in ruby

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, instance

I want to compare one class (Paper) name to other class (Rock) name inside different class.

In other words how can I call the Paper object variable inside the Rock object by passing the object as an argument?

Here is my code, the if statement under the Rock class is problem.

```
class Element
    attr_accessor name

    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end

    def compare_to(name)
        fail "This method should be overridden"
    end
end

class Rock < Element 
    def compare_to(ob1)
        if @name == @@ob1
            return "do something"
        end 

        return "help"
    end
end

class Paper < Element 
    def compare_to(var)
    end
end

rock = Rock.new('Rock')
paper = Paper.new('Paper')

puts rock.compare_to(paper)
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you mean by "call a class variable"? You cannot "call" a variable. The only thing that can be called in Ruby is a method. And even that is not entirely true, you can only send a message, and the runtime may or may not invoke a method as a response. Also, you never show how the class variable is initialized, and you never show which class it belongs to. Also, you only say that there *is* a problem, but you don't say what the problem is. Do you get an error? What is the error? Do you get a wrong result? What is the wrong result, and what would be the right

Comment: … result? Is the behavior not what you expect? What is the behavior you expect, and what is the behavior you observe instead? https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: The possibility to create `Rock.new('Paper')` or `Paper.new('Scissors')` might be an indication that something isn’t quite right.

Comment: You never assign a value to your class variable `@@ob1`.  What's the point then in doing a `@name == @@ob1`?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the *instance* variable `@name` (it is not a class variable) of the other object by calling the getter method you generated with `attr_accessor :name` (please note that there is a `:` missing in that line in your example).

Just change the `compare_to` in your child model to:

```
def compare_to(ob1)
  if @name == ob1.name
    return "do something"
  end 

  return "help"
end
```